# How can I override route in AngularUI Router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

Using AngularUI Router can I have a way in which more than one state matches the requested URL but the one which satisfies first kicks in.

I have 2 states `catalog.category` for catalog page and `catalog.product` for product page.

Category State:

```
        $stateProvider
            .state('catalog.category', {
                url: '/shop/category/{slug:.*}',
                controller: 'CategoryCtrl'
            });
```

Product State:

```
        $stateProvider
            .state('catalog.product', {
                url: "/shop/category/{categorySlug:.*}/product/{productSlug}",
                controller: 'ProductCtrl',
            });
```

How do I get `/shop/category/men/apparel` match `catalog.category` state and `/shop/category/men/apparel/product/black-tshirt` match `catalog.product` state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/42ws7lfAqaljn75xa0va?p=preview). What we have to do, is to define more precise *(the second state)* as the first. If it will be evaluated against the regex (url) ... it will be found first:

```
.state('catalog.product', {
    url: "/shop/category/{categorySlug:.*}/product/{productSlug}",
    controller: 'ProductCtrl',
    ...
  })
.state('catalog.catagory', {
    url: '/shop/category/{slug:.*}',
    controller: 'CategoryCtrl',
    ...
  })
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/42ws7lfAqaljn75xa0va?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked. I was trying to define these 2 states in different modules which didn't work. But I realized the problem was while injecting the module dependencies. I was injecting category module before product module.

Comment: Yes exactly. In this case the order is essential ;) great if that worked! ;) enjoy the awesome `ui-router`

Answer (score 0):

What about nested states?

```
        $stateProvider
        .state('catalog.category', {
            url: '/shop/category/{slug:.*}',
            controller: 'CategoryCtrl'
        });

        $stateProvider
        .state('catalog.category.product', {
            url: "/product/{productSlug}",
            controller: 'ProductCtrl',
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Didn't work. The problem is I have `/` in my slug so it never reaches the child state.